# How to render a plane of seemingly infinite size?

Tags: c++, opengl

How can i render a textured plane at some z-pos to be visible towards infinity?

I could achieve this by drawing really huge plane, but if i move my camera off the ground to higher altitude, then i would start to see the plane edges, which i want to avoid being seen.

If this is even possible, i would prefer non-shader method.

**Edit:** i tried with the 4d coordinate system as suggested, but: it works horribly bad. my textures will get distorted even at camera position 100, so i would have to draw multiple textured quads anyways. perhaps i could do that, and draw the farthest quads with the 4d coordinate system? any better ideas?

**Edit2:** for those who dont have a clue what opengl texture distortion is, here's example from the tests i did with 4d vertex coords:
[image]

(in case image not visible: http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/469/texturedistort.jpg )
note that it only happens when camera gets far enough, in this case its only 100.0 units away from middle! (middle = (0,0) where my 4 triangles starts to go towards infinity). usually this happens around at 100000.0 or something. but with 4d vertices it seems to happen earlier for some reason.

Comment: Obviously, you can't render it to infinity. Determine your vanishing point and render it to there. Perhaps you should describe what you're *actually* trying to accomplish, not how you decided you think you should achieve it.

Comment: Indeed, you can also setup fog so the transition from textured plane to nothingness is less abrupt.

Comment: @DeadMG: Its not particularly hard really ... you are only ever rendering 4 points aren't you?

Comment: @Tomalak, i have a vague memory that this could be done in 4d somehow, is that true? what im trying: i have a skybox, but i dont want the bottom (ground) to be out of my reach, so i want to walk on it, thus, i need a plane that goes to infinity, just like the 5 other planes in the skybox. at DeadMG: theres no team, why i prefer non-shader, because of what i said: i have a hunch this could be done just using 4d vertices. and i prefer to make things simple at first.

Comment: That well-known 4D environment that we all live in.

Comment: Your "thus" is a complete non sequitur. Where does "infinity" come into it at all?

Comment: @Tomalak, pardon, english is my third language. i just want to optimize the ground rendering so i dont have to render billions of quads depending on my camera angle/position. So, if i go in higher altitude, i would need to render more and more quads (assuming i cant render just one quad since it would probably start to bug on large sizes)

Comment: Why would there be problems with just rendering 1 quad?

Comment: @Tomalak No, the 4D projective geometry environment your rendered geometry lives in.

Comment: @Tomalak and pals, check my edits, still trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Hah; I love the image <3

Comment: fintelia is right, what is the problem with a single quad? And you can draw it to the distance you tell opengl to clip from then on (for example the zfar in `gluPerspective`). The thing is, beyond that z, you can't really draw anything and if that is not far enough for you, well you just have to increase the zfar.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot render an object of infinite size.

You are more than likely confusing the concept of projection with rendering objects of infinite size. A 4D homogeneous coordinate who's W is 0 represents a 3D position that is at infinity relative to the projection. But that doesn't mean a point infinitely far from the camera; it means a point infinitely *close* to the camera. That is, it represents a point who's Z coordinate (before multiplication with the perspective projection matrix) was equal to the camera position (in camera space, this is 0).

See under perspective projection, a point that is in the same plane as the camera is infinitely far away on the X and Y axes. That is the nature of the perspective projection. 4D homogeneous coordinates allow you to give them all finite numbers, and therefore you can do useful mathematics to them (like clipping).

4D homogeneous coordinates do not allow you to represent an infinitely large surface.

Comment: so how would you do this effect then? as i posted the image, there is a problem, do you know how to fix this problem? i tried moving the plane under my camera, but it didnt help.

Comment: @Rookie: Just render a plane. If making it larger than some particular value causes texture distortion, then render multiple squares that are all smaller than that size.

Comment: but towards the horizon i need more and more planes to render, eventually i would need infinite amount of planes, right? so i need 4d vertices for the edges at least. is this what you would do?

Comment: @Rookie: I thought "You cannot render an object of infinite size," was pretty clear. You cannot cram infinity into a finite space, and OpenGL is most assuredly _finite_. It has finite floating-point precision, and it has finite limits to its depth range. Rendering anything outside of the depth range will be clipped (or clamped if you turn near/far clipping off). The best you can do is "arbitrarily large". Further, a truly infinite plane has no horizon; you are either viewing it edge-on, or it fills your entire view.

Comment: its not infinite to the screen coordinates, thats pretty much my point. try and draw a grid, and then look the grid in perspective, you will see the lines distance to previous lines will get lower and lower until its nearly zero. this is what i want, i want to draw a plane to the point when it is "zero" thus no more pixels can be rendered on the screen. or take a skybox,and draw a line in middle of the horizon, the line will never change its place when you move up/down, thus it has infinite distance. this is what i want to do, but i want to draw a plane from that skybox horizon under my feets.

Comment: i think the problem here is that you think i want to bend the world logics/physics and make infinite finite, which isnt obviously possible. I only want to **emulate** the infinity, so it **looks** like infinite. i edited the question title to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing an infinitely large plane is easy - all you need is to compute the horizon line in screen coordinates. To do so, you have to simply take two non-collinear 4D directions (say, [1, 0, 0, 0] and [0, 0, 1, 0]), then compute their position on the screen (by multiplying manually with the view-matrix and the projection matrix, and then clipping into viewport coordinates. When you have these two points, you can compute a 2D line through the screen and clip it against it. There, you have your infinity plane (the lower polygon). However, it is difficult to display a texture on this plane, because it would be infinitely large. But if your texture is simple (e.g. a grid), then you can compute it yourself with 4D coordinates, using the same schema like above - computing points and their corresponding vanishing point and connecting them.